# Can not stop an animation with a callback

Tags: react-native

I tried to make a repeated animation, and at first I use the setInterval() to achieve this , but the result seems not well because there is a small break between animations.
And I tried to use the callback in start() :

```
 _rotate(){
    this.state.rotation.setValue(0)

    Animated.timing(
        this.state.rotation,
        {
            duration:this.speed,
            toValue:1,
        }
    ).start( this._rotate.bind(this) )

}
```

Expected a continuously animation , but the result is just like the situation when using setInterval().
And, when there is no callback in start() , I can use

```
this.state.rotation.stopAnimation()
```

to stop the animation. But with the callback , it does not work.

Maybe I missed something. Anyone helps?

---

After digging into the source code, it seems that Facebook need to do more on the react-native document.
The callback in start should be like this:

```
//AnimatedImplementation.js
type EndCallback = (result: EndResult) => void;
```

So , I changed my code to:

```
_rotate(result){
this.state.rotation.setValue(0)

Animated.timing(
    this.state.rotation,
    {
        duration:this.speed,
        toValue:1,
    }
).start( this._rotate.bind(this,result) )
}
```

Then, the problem is gone....

Comment: Have you tried this: `).start(() =>  this._rotate())` <= This worked for me doing something similar.

Comment: Oh,yeah. It works.. But, still don't know why...